# Why is ffmpeg warning "Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : mono"?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to read and write raw audio to/from my python script.  Both the save and load commands I use produce the warning "Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : mono"?  This is despite that fact that I am telling ffmpeg using `-ac 1` before both the input and output that there is only one channel.  I saw some other answers where I should set `-guess_layout_max 0` but this seems like a hack since I don't want ffmpeg to guess; I am telling it exactly how many channels there are with `-ac 1`.  It should not need to make any guess.

My save command is formatted as follows with `r` being the sample rate and `f` being the file I want to save the raw audio to.  I am sending raw audio via stdin from python over a pipe.

`ffmpeg_cmd = 'ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel warning -y -ar %d -ac 1 -f u16le -i pipe: -ac 1 %s' % (r, shlex.quote(f))`

Likewise my load command is the following with ffmpeg reading from `f` and writing raw audio to stdout.

`ffmpeg_cmd = 'ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel warning -i %s -ar %d -ac 1 -f u16le -c:a pcm_u16le -ac 1 pipe:' % (shlex.quote(f), r)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`-ac` sets no. of channels, not their layout, of which there can be multiple for each value of a channel count.

Use the option `-channel_layout`.

`ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel warning -y -ar %d -ac 1 -channel_layout mono -f u16le -i pipe: ...`

Comment: Thanks that seems to work.  For my read command I still need to add it before the -i even though I am reading an mp3.  Shouldn't ffmpeg just know the number of channels in an mp3?  `ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel warning -channel_layout mono -i %s -ar %d -ac 1 -f u16le -c:a pcm_u16le pipe:`

Comment: the `-channel_layout mono` or `-channel_layout stereo` has no effect regardless of position (ffmpeg v6.0)